# enable scroll on body with absolue position div

Tags: html, css, scroll, position

Inside the body element, I have div with `position: absolute;` I'm trying to execute scroll option on this page with `window.scrollTo(0,500)`.

I can't change the position from absolute to something else.

It is possible to do scroll with those conditions?

```
<div id="body>
    <div id ="main>
    </div>
</div>

main{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 1rem 0;
  background: #bdf;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

and:

```
body {
margin: 0;
overflow: scroll
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you try like this,

```
setTimeout(function() { window.scrollTo(0, 500); }, 0);
```

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work, my body height is 0 because of the absolute position of the inner div so I can't do any scroll on the page

Comment: Then can you please provide an appropriate snippet so I can check what you have done so far.